# How to get the node list from given xml using XPATH in Java

Tags: java, xml, xpath

Find the total number of category elements in first tuple of item with post Id = **131145**. The given XPATH expression works perfectly in online simulator, but when I try to execute with Java XPath library (it returns 0). Please let me know what am I doing wrong here and what would be the correct version of XPath expression for Java.

**Given XML:**

```
<rss>
<channel>
    <item>
           <post_id>131145</post_id>    
           <category domain="news-destination" nicename="civonline"><![CDATA[civonline]]></category>
           <category domain="category" nicename="cronaca"><![CDATA[Cronaca]]></category>
           <category domain="news-source" nicename="dbsource"><![CDATA[Database Civonline]]></category>
           <category domain="news-destination" nicename="laprovincia"><![CDATA[laprovincia]]></category>
           <category domain="comune" nicename="tarquinia"><![CDATA[Tarquinia]]></category>
    </item>
    <item>
           <post_id>123456</post_id>    
           <category domain="news-destination1" nicename="civonline"><![CDATA[civonline]]></category>
           <category domain="category1" nicename="cronaca"><![CDATA[Cronaca]]></category>
           <category domain="news-source1" nicename="dbsource"><![CDATA[Database Civonline]]></category>
           <category domain="news-destination1" nicename="laprovincia"><![CDATA[laprovincia]]></category>
           <category domain="comune1" nicename="tarquinia"><![CDATA[Tarquinia]]></category>
    </item>
</channel>
```

**XPATH Expression:** `/rss/channel/item[post_id='131145']//*[name()='category']`

**Online Simulator:** https://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html

**Expected Result:**

```
Element='<category domain="news-destination" nicename="civonline">civonline</category>' 
Element='<category domain="category" nicename="cronaca">Cronaca</category>' 
Element='<category domain="news-source" nicename="dbsource">Database Civonline</category>' 
Element='<category domain="news-destination" nicename="laprovincia" >laprovincia </category>'
Element='<category domain="comune" nicename="tarquinia">Tarquinia</category>'
```

**Java CodeSnippet:**

```
String xpath_suffix = WP_ITEM_CATEGORY_XPATH + "[post_id='" + item.getPostId() + "']//*[name()='category']";
NodeList categoryNodeList = readXMLNodeList(doc, xpath_suffix);
System.out.println("Category List: " + categoryNodeList.item(0));

protected NodeList readXMLNodeList(Object item, String xpathExpression) throws XPathExpressionException {
    return (NodeList) readXML(item, xpathExpression, XPathConstants.NODESET);
}
 
protected Object readXML(Object item, String xpathExpression, QName returnType) throws XPathExpressionException {
    XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
    XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile(xpathExpression);
    return expr.evaluate(item, returnType);
}
```

**Java Result:**

0 found

**Note:** How can we fix it XPath expression for Java to give same expected result.

Comment: Please show your Java code.

Comment: @vanje: It's updated. Please let me know.

Comment: Please show minimal but complete samples allowing others to reproduce the problem. It is not clear why your code doing e.g. `System.out.println("Category List: " + categoryNodeList.item(0));` should output `0 found`.

Comment: Why `//*[name()='category']` and not just `//category`?

Comment: You haven’t shown us the value of `WP_ITEM_CATEGORY_XPATH`.  But `xpath.evaluate("/rss/channel/item[post_id='" + postID + "']//category", doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);` worked for me on your example XML.

Comment: @VGR - `WP_ITEM_CATEGORY_XPATH="/rss/channel/item" + "[post_id='" + item.getPostId() + "']//*[name()='category']"`. Your change removing the *name* didn't work for me with JAVA. The XPATH expression works in online simulator but not in JAVA.

Comment: @VGR - `NodeList categoryNodeList` returns 0. Not expected result set - which is 5 node elements of category.

Comment: How sure are you that `getPostId()` returns the value you expect it to return?  You may want to print that value out.  And perhaps print out its length, too, just in case it contains non-printing characters.

Comment: Java code with XPath `/rss/channel/item[post_id='131145']//category` works fine at https://onecompiler.com/java/3yxq4thsv to find five element nodes. Output is not the same as in your online tester but they somehow serialize the returned nodes, either by using some other object model which does that automatically for nodes (like Saxon) or by using an identity Transformer or LSSerializer for DOM.